# Arraylist não faz display correto

Tags: java, arraylist

Tenho uma super classe Pessoa com 2 sub classes (Aluno e Professor). Entretanto fiz outra classe "Lista" para criar o ArrayList e mais tarde manusear tudo.

Na hora de usar a Lista os dados são aceites mas quando tento ler o conteudo da lista o que me é mostrado está errado.

O codigo é o seguinte:
Classe Aluno

```
package aula38;

public class Aluno extends Pessoa { //extend permite usar campos da classe a que se extende

    private String curso;
    private double notas;

    //public Aluno(String nome, String endereco, String telefone, String curso) {     }

    public Aluno(String curso, String nome, String endereco, String telefone) {
        super(nome, endereco, telefone);
        this.curso = curso;
       // this.notas = notas;
    }

    public String getCurso() {
        return curso;
    }

    public void setCurso(String curso) {
        this.curso = curso;
    }

    public double getNotas() {
        return notas;
    }

    public void setNotas(double notas) {
        this.notas = notas;
    }

}
```

Classe Professor

```
package aula38;

public class Professor extends Pessoa {

    private double salario;
    private String nomeCurso;

    /**
     *
     * @param salario
     * @param nomeCurso
     * @param nome
     * @param endereco
     * @param telefone
     */

    public Professor(double salario, String nomeCurso, String nome, String endereco, String telefone) {
        super(nome, endereco, telefone);
        this.salario = salario;
        this.nomeCurso = nomeCurso;
    }

    public double getSalario() {
        return salario;
    }

    public void setSalario(double salario) {
        this.salario = salario;
    }

    public String getNomeCurso() {
        return nomeCurso;
    }

    public void setNomeCurso(String nomeCurso) {
        this.nomeCurso = nomeCurso;
    }

}
```

Classe Pessoa

```
package aula38;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Pessoa {
    private String nome;
    private String endereco;
    private String telefone;



    public Pessoa(String nome, String endereco, String telefone) {
        this.nome = nome;
        this.endereco = endereco;
        this.telefone = telefone;
    }


    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    public String getEndereco() {
        return endereco;
    }

    public void setEndereco(String endereco) {
        this.endereco = endereco;
    }

    public String getTelefone() {
        return telefone;
    }

    public void setTelefone(String telefone) {
        this.telefone = telefone;
    }
}
```

Classe Lista

```
    package aula38;


import aula38.Pessoa;
import java.util.ArrayList;

/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

/**
 *
 * @author Jos
 */
public class Lista {
    private ArrayList<Pessoa> gente;

    public Lista() {
        gente = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public void adicionarGente(Pessoa a){
        gente.add(a);
    }

    public void Listar(){
        for(Pessoa a: gente){
            System.out.println(a);
        }
    }

}
```

Classe Aula38

```
package aula38;

public class Aula38 {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Lista lista = new Lista();

    lista.adicionarGente(new Pessoa("Maria","Rua 2", "92550421"));
    lista.adicionarGente(new Aluno("Luca", "Rua 20", "942110422", "TIC"));
    lista.adicionarGente(new Professor (500, "TIC", "Jorge", "Rua 21", "215225682"));

    lista.Listar(); // nao faz o display correto dos valores acima

    } 
}
```

E o display é:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguem me pode dizer o que está errado?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Todos os objetos Java possuem um método `toString()`, que é invocado quando você tenta imprimir o objeto.

```
System.out.println(a); // invoca a.toString()
```

Este método é definido na class [`Object`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html) (a superclasse de todos os objetos Java). O método [`Object.toString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString--) retorna uma string, composta pelo nome da classe, um símbolo `@` e o `hashcode` do objeto em hexadecimal.

```
// Código de Object.toString()
public String toString() {
    return getClass().getName() + "@" + Integer.toHexString(hashCode());
}
```

Seu resultado `aula38.Pessoa@15db9742` pode ser explicado como:

- `aula38.Pessoa` - o nome da classe. Neste caso, a classe `Pessoa` está no pacote `aula38`.
- `@` - junta a string.
- `15db9742` - o hashcode do objeto.

Para imprimir algo diferente quando você chama `System.out.println(meuObjeto)`, você deve sobrescrever o método `toString()` na sua própria classe. Por exemplo, na superclasse `Pessoa`, adicionando

```
@Override
public String toString() {
  return getClass().getSimpleName() + "[nome=" + this.nome + "]";
}
```

você terá como resultado

> Pessoa[nome=Maria]
>
> Aluno[nome=Rua 20]
>
> Professor[nome=Jorge]

Exemplo [online](https://repl.it/IqFS/0).